# Windows Form refresh datagridview

Tags: winforms, datagridview, refresh

I am fairly new to c# and Windows forms. My problem is I need to refresh a bound datagridview when I add an appointment or on a timer if no appointment is entered. I have three forms. Form 1 is log in screen which opens and populates the appointments in Form 3. On enter of space bar opens Form 2 which is populated with appointment information. On button click to save Form 2 I need Form 3 to refresh. This is my first post, hope I am making sense, I have tried to solve this for weeks. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show an example of your code, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: Are you closing form 2 after each entry of appointment information?

Comment: yes jaredbaszsler Form 2 closes each time an appointment is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Form2, add this for your button clicked event handler which will call back to your Form3 singleton instance:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3.Instance.RefreshGrid();
}
```

Then in your Form3, you need a property to hold the singleton instance of the form, and a method to refresh the grid:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private static Form3 _instance;

    public static Form3 Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public Form3()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = this;
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
        this.dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mangist, I did exactly as you said I get this error - Error 1 Type 'namespace.Form3' already defines a member called 'Form3' with the same parameter types

Comment: Check the code again, those private and public static members need to go inside your Form3.

Comment: public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private static Form3 _instance;
        public static Form3 Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }               

        private Form1 form1;

        
        public Form3()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = this;
            }
            InitializeComponent();
            BindGrid();

Comment: Don't add a new file to your project. Put those properties and the method from Form3 into your Form3 class. You've got 2 Form3s now.

Comment: HI Mangist I did what you suggested but it is still not refreshing the grid.

Comment: Hi have stepped through the code when the  int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Form3.Instance.RefreshGrid();

Comment: Hi have stepped through the code when the  int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Form3.Instance.RefreshGrid(); is passed it goes to the Public static Form3 Instance { get {return _instance} then back to Form3.Instance.RefreshGrid(); then public void RefreshGrid()
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
        }                                                                                                                     then Form3.Instance.RefreshGrid(); then this.Close(); then finishes with  f2.ShowDialog();

Comment: You need to set the data source on your grid inside RefreshGrid if you're reloading data from your database. Post your code for your grid form and I can help.

Comment: public void BindGrid()
{
String connectionString = @"Data Source";

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Appointments  ORDER BY Time ASC)
   {

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
      {

       using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
       {

          sda.Fill(dt);
                                
          dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                                

        }

      }

    }
  }
}

Comment: Thank you for your help Mangist much appreciated.

Comment: I presume you got this working? In the RefreshGrid() method you need to requery the SQL database and call your BindGrid() method. Please mark this as answered if you were able to use the code I posted.

Comment: Sorry Mangist I have looked, how do I mark as answered.